# state not updating in SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

I am currently building this e-commerce store and I want to have a modal as my cart using skeleton UI. Everything works except that the cart doesn't update immediately, but if I close the modal and open it again everything works fine. I also use the local storage store by skeleton UI.
Here is my cart.svelte:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import CartProduct from './cartProduct.svelte';
    import { cartItems } from './cart';
    import { get, writable, type Writable } from 'svelte/store';
    import { getProductData } from '../routes/products';

    let subtotal = writable(0);
    const getSubtotal = () => {
        let total = 0;
        $cartItems.forEach((item) => {
            if (item && item.id) {
                const productData = getProductData(item.id);
                if (productData) {
                    total += productData.price * item.quantity;
                }
            }
        });
        subtotal.set(total);
    };

    $: getSubtotal();
</script>

<div class="bg-surface-100-800-token card p-8 w-[90%] max-h-[70dvh] relative">
    <h1 class="h1 font-black mb-4">Your Cart:</h1>
    <div class="overflow-auto max-h-[40dvh]">
        {#each $cartItems as item}
            <CartProduct itemId={item.id} />
        {/each}
    </div>
    <p>Subtotal: {$subtotal}</p>
    <button
        class="btn variant-ghost-primary mt-4 h3 font-bold"
        on:click={() => console.log('Checkout')}>Check out</button
    >
</div>
```

Here is my cart.ts:

```
import { get, type Writable } from 'svelte/store';
import { localStorageStore } from '@skeletonlabs/skeleton';

export const cartItems: Writable<CartItem[]> = localStorageStore<CartItem[]>('cartItems', []);

export const addToCart = (id: string) => {
    let items = get(cartItems);
    let itemPosition = items.findIndex((item) => {
        return item.id === id;
    });

    if (itemPosition === -1) {
        cartItems.update(() => {
            return [...items, { id: id, quantity: 1 }];
        });
    } else {
        return items;
    }
};

export const removeFromCart = (id: string) => {
    let items = get(cartItems);
    let itemPosition = items.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);

    if (itemPosition !== -1) {
        cartItems.update((cartItems) => {
            return cartItems.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
        });
    }
};
```

The state of the cart should be updated in realtime in my modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reactive statement

```js
    $: getSubtotal();
```

by itself has very limited use  because it has no right-hand side variable to be reactive upon. This causes the statement to run only once - when the component (i.e. your modal) is instantied.

Try modifying the signature of your function to

```js
    const getSubtotal = (items) => {
        let total = 0;
        items.forEach((item) => {
            if (item && item.id) {
                const productData = getProductData(item.id);
                if (productData) {
                    total += productData.price * item.quantity;
                }
            }
        });
        subtotal.set(total);
    };
```

and your reactive statement to

```js
    $: getSubtotal($cartItems);
```

which in effect is saying "run this function again everytime `$cartItems` changes", and then uses the updated `$cartItems` value as a parameter in your computation function.

Comment: thanks, I got one more question: why does the cart itself so the cartitems in the cart not update, because when I have multiple items in my cart and I delete one, in the background it deletes the correct one, but I see the wrong one being deleted. So there's also a state problem there

Comment: @NevilleBrem That is because your item iteration is unkeyed, so Svelte misses the correct reference as to which element to remove from the DOM. You should be able to fix that by updating your `#each` statement to `{#each $cartItems as item (item.id)}` - whatever you specify in the parens is the *key* for each iteratee and has to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```js
$: getSubtotal();
```

Makes little sense. You use not state/reactive variable here, so this will only get computed when the component is created. To make it rerun when `$cartItems` is updated, you must use `$cartItems` within this re-active block, e.g.:

```js
$: $cartItems && getSubtotal();
```

But I find this solution nicer:

```js
const getSubtotal = (cartItems) => {
    let total = 0;
    cartItems.forEach((item) => {
        if (item && item.id) {
            const productData = getProductData(item.id);
            if (productData) {
                total += productData.price * item.quantity;
            }
        }
    });
    return total
};

$: subtotal = getSubtotal($cartItems);
```

Now `getSubtotal()` is independent of Svelte-specific things, and is easier to test.